# What is wrong with apt-get?

Tags: apt

I can see and `apt-get` in `/usr/bin/`:

```
gradinafrica@host:/usr/bin$ ls -l apt-get
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178608 Apr 20  2012 apt-get
```

But when I try to run it, I get

```
gradinafrica@host:/usr/bin$ apt-get
-bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
```

I think I may have messed it up. Is there a way to reinstall it without completely reinstalling Ubuntu?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, btw

EDIT:

PATH: `/home/gradinafrica/.dnx/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Also, `sudo`ing and/or running directly from `/usr/bin` (ie `cd /usr/bin && sudo ./apt-get`) give the same output; they don't help.

Comment: What does `file /usr/bin/apt-get` say?

Comment: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF 32-bit LSB  
executable, Intel 80386, version 1
 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses 
shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24
, BuildID[sha1]=2bfee6c630165339
6534c1646e4c787f198542, stripped

Comment: have you tried using sudo? btw, when I want to run something from the current directory, I usually do it like so: `./apt-get` or `sudo ./apt-get`

Comment: gradinafrica@host:/usr/bin$ sudo . /apt-get [sudo] password for gradinafrica:  sudo: unable to execute ./apt-get:  No such file or directory

Comment: Please run the command `echo $PATH` and let us know the output by editing your question.

Comment: PATH: `/home/gradinafrica/.dnx/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a really old version of apt. I think the last security update for apt was on october of 2014 and should at least have a different build id.

In any case, run the following commands:

```
cd
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb
sudo rm /usr/bin/apt-get
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_i386.deb
```

please post any errors

---

**EDIT**

Okay, since it didn't want to install at first, we can at least copy the new apt-get files to where they need to go to get things started. Run the following commands:

```
cd 
mkdir aptget
cp apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_i386.deb aptget
cd aptget
ar xvf *
tar xvf data*
sudo mv ./usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin
sudo mv ./usr/bin/apt /usr/bin
```

Now, run apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: okay, i fixed that last command if it didn't run for you

Comment: /usr/bin/apt doesn't exist.  Did you mean /usr/bin/apt-get?

Comment: dpkg: error processing package apt  (--install):  dependency problems - leaving unc onfigured Processing triggers for man-db (2. 6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ... Errors were encountered while proc essing:  apt

Comment: Just the error; the entire output wouldn't fit in the input box

Comment: @BrianGradin I have included some steps to manually insert the /usr/bin files

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get `/usr/bin/apt` and `/usr/bin/apt-get` back using those steps. I verified they were there by `ls -a /usr/bin | less` and hitting space a couple times.  But when I run `sudo /usr/bin/apt-get update`, I still get `sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory`...

Comment: I'm in an ssh session; I don't have a GUI

Comment: If I try to execute `apt-get` before I move it to `/usr/bin`, I get the same error: `sudo: unable to execute ./apt-get: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think my version of Ubuntu is 64 bit, and it says the `apt-get` you had me download is 32-bit. Is there a 64-bit package?

Comment: Right, and it wasn't working.  Is there a 64-bit version?

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

You're currently in `/usr/bin`, therefore

If you want to run an executable file in the directory you're currently browsing, you should go for

```
$ ./executable_name
```

and not

```
$ executable_name
```

Comment: Actually that's not necessary when the executable is in PATH (which might not be the case here).

Comment: This is the right answer I believe. OP is in `usr/bin`

Comment: `/usr/bin` is in PATH, so just typing `sudo apt-get` should reference the correct executable. In any case, even if I `cd /usr/bin` and run `sudo ./apt-get update`, I get `sudo: unable to execute ./apt-get: No such file or directory`